# mysql query to chop up whole words

Tags: mysql

I have a title for an add ie:
"sweet apple cider"

what I want to do is split the whole words into separate sections so I can then run a query for each instance

```
select * from db where title like '%sweet%'

select * from db where title like '%apple%'

select * from db where title like '%cider%'
```

So if no results on first, trys the second and so on until a result is found if not nothing is displayed... its like using similar items found.

Hope that's clear. Thanks

Comment: How many results are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to try based on if there's nothing. But you can limit it to, let's say, 2 items this way:

```
SELECT       * FROM `db` WHERE `title` LIKE '%sweet%'
UNION SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `title` LIKE '%apple%'
UNION SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `title` LIKE '%cider%'
LIMIT 0, 2
```

Or, if you want to get the title that way, you need to use `OR` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `db`
  WHERE `title` LIKE '%sweet%'
  OR    `title` LIKE '%apple%'
  OR    `title` LIKE '%cider%'
```

Comment: your assuming i know the title, i dont, i need a sql that chops the title if there is any too chop, could be one word could be 5 words, hope thats clearer